# Show image on hover

Tags: javascript, html

I need to hide a image and when I put the mouse on the spot where should be visible, it appears. How should I do it?

**HTML:**

```
<img onclick="stergeSertar(this)"  onhover="arataX" src="img/x2.png" style="position: relative;aligh:center;z-index:600" class="xSertar" id="'+id+'xS">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function arataX(x){
  var idX=x.id+"xS";
  $("#"+idX).toggleClass('active');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.xSertar{
  position:relative;
  visibility:hidden;
  margin-left=-10px;

}

.xSertar:hover{
  position:relative;
  margin-left=-10px;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: `visibility: visible` does not override `display: none;`. You need to have `display: block;` or `display: inline` in your hover class. Also in your html, you need to modify your **style** `align` property. It's `text-align: center;`. And just as a side note, I don't think HTML has a native `onhover` event. It's `onmouseover`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:202px;
    height:202px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
div:hover img {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3zCfZ/

Answer (score 2):

Is this the answer you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/waFTK/

**CSS**

```
.img{
    float:left;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    background:url('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b69232a748a7a33c9a9d3dd4dba4c62c?s=75&d=identicon&r=PG');
    border:0;
    outline:0;
}

.img:hover{
    background:none;
}
```

You can't hover over an element that's invisible, so that's why the image is set as background image here and removed when hovered. (The element however remains visible.

Comment: +1 for using `background-image`